# merging several images with imagecopyresized

Tags: php, image, merge

I want to merge several images into one. I have this array down below.

**$products_settings** - array:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (            
        [product_left] => 368
        [product_top] => 317
        [product_width] => 67.0
        [product_height] => 85.0
        [product_file] => /whateverfile1.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_left] => 569
        [product_top] => 459
        [product_width] => 67.0
        [product_height] => 85.0
        [product_file] => /whateverfile2.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_left] => 710
        [product_top] => 359
        [product_width] => 67.0
        [product_height] => 85.0
        [product_file] => /whateverfile3.jpg
    )

)
```

I've tried this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

foreach($products_settings as &$ps) {

    //Original-product/image-file
    $filename = $ps['product_file'];
    list($source_width, $source_height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    //Destination image (as large as outfit-area-canvas)
    $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor(intval($canvas_settings['width_canvas']), intval($canvas_settings['height_canvas']));
    $dest_width = intval($ps['product_width']);
    $dest_height = intval($ps['product_height']);
    $dest_x = intval($ps['product_left']);
    $dest_y = intval($ps['product_top']);

    //Resize source-image to new width and height and then copy from source to destination              
    imagecopyresized($dest_image, $source_image, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $dest_width, $dest_height, $source_width, $source_height);

    imagejpeg($dest_image, 'dummy.jpg');

}
?>
```

Only the last image (*in this case whateverfile3.jpg*) in the array `$products_settings` are merged into file dummy.jpg, but I want to merge all three products into file dummy.jpg. How could I achieve that? Please give me some pointers!

Comment: Well, it starts with thinking about what belongs before the loop, what into the loop and which part after the loop. Right now you only have in the loop which - as you already realized - is counter-productive.

Comment: @hakre - I've supplied the array (it's the products_settings array). The image resources are created correctly, left, top, width, height is created and merged correctly into dummy.jpg - it works with one array-item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep recreating the destination image on each loop...put it before the loop starts.

Then output the image after all the loops are complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've figured it out now! :-)